# Editing patch of a past commit

Tags: git, patch

I have a past commit containing a line in its patch which shall be a part of a newer commit. Is there any way I can move this line from one patch to the other? I am trying to play around with `edit` option of `git rebase --interactive`, but I cannot get to change the patch. Is this even possible?

Comment: Interesting. I think edit option should work. What's the behavior you are observing? The rebase doesn't stop for you to edit the commit? Also I think you need to edit both the old and your new commit right?

Comment: Rebase stops and says I can do `git commit --amend`. When I do this, a text editor pops up, but it does not contain any patches, only the commit message.

Comment: OK so when rebase stops, you need to actually modify your code(which, for the past commit, remove the one line; for your new commit, add that line). After that code change is saved, run git add, then git commit --amend.

Comment: @congbaoguier This was not a comment but an answer. Just sayin'

Comment: @congbaoguier that's it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want, using an interactive rebase.  But note a key point: commits aren't patches!  Commits are *snapshots*.  Each commit has a *full copy of all of your source* even though `git log -p` *shows* each commit as a patch.

The reason `git log -p` shows the commits as patches, even though they're snapshots, is obvious: it's much more *useful* to say *commit #12 is just a little bit different from commit #11, and here's the difference* than it is to say: *Here's commit #12, and hah! You're on your own, sucker!*  So `git log -p` works by extracting commit #11 *and* commit #12, comparing the two, and then showing you what *changed.*

You should keep this in the back of your mind at all times: commits are snapshots; but Git likes to *compare* two snapshots to show you what changed between them.  You can pick any two snapshots to compare, but `git log -p`, and other Git commands, will automatically use the two adjacent parent/child commits.  Rebase's copying works this way too: it compares parent and child, to see what to do.  (To compare two commits of your choosing, you can use `git diff` and simply name the two commits to compare.)

You might also want to know that it's technically impossible to change any existing commit.  Rebase can't do that, and doesn't try.  What `git rebase` does is to *copy* the old (flawed) commits to new-and-improved ones.  The old commits stick around, at least for a while, and you can get them back if your new and improved commits actually turn out to be new and worse.

---

With all that said, here's how to do this with interactive rebase.  Begin by choosing a commit *before* the ones you need to improve:

```
9abcdef  Subject of last commit
00afde4  Second to last commit that should have more stuff
badc0de  The commit that you dislike
ba5eba5  A commit you're OK with
```

Here, commit `badc0de` is the one you'd like to replace with a new-and-improved commit.  You want some change you made *in* `badc0de` to go into `00afde4` instead, so you really want to replace `badc0de` with a different commit that does less, and `00afde4` with another different commit that does more.  Then, because `9abcdef` says *my parent is `00afde4`* you're going to have to copy `9abcdef` to a new and improved commit whose only improvement is going to be to say *my parent is _______*, where the blank gets filled in by making the new and improved version of `00afde4`.

So, now you will run `git rebase -i ba5eba5` and get an instruction sheet in your editor that reads:

```
pick badc0de The commit that you dislike
pick 00afde4 Second to last commit that should have more stuff
pick 9abcdef Subject of last commit
```

(Note that while `git log` starts from the *end* and works backwards, the instruction sheet for `git rebase -i` starts with the first commit you'll copy-but-change-while-copying and moves *forwards*.)

Since we're assuming here that you want to put the line from `badc0de` into `00afde4`, you should now change these two of the three `pick` commands to read `edit`, leaving `9abcdef`—which you'd like to copy without changes—as a `pick` command.  Write the instruction sheet back to whatever file it's in, and exit the editor to start Git following the instructions.

Git will now copy commit `badc0de`, but then stop so that you can *change* the copy.  Technically, it hasn't actually *copied* `badc0de` yet—it's just set things up so that what you do next *will* copy it—but in more complex cases like we're about to see, it will have made a temporary copy.  You're now in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode—not on any branch at all—and what you do is run your editor to edit whichever file(s) should be different, change them, write them out, and exit your editor.  Then you `git add` each such file and run:

```
git commit --amend
```

This shoves `badc0de` out of the way on this detached-HEAD branch, making the copy of the `badc0de` commit that's now a *good* commit.  We don't know what hash ID it *will* have, but let's call it `1111111` for purpose of referring to it.

Now that you have `1111111` with parent `ba5eba5` and with the snapshot you want, run:

```
git rebase --continue
```

to resume the interactive rebase.  Git now goes on to copy `00afde4` to a new temporary commit.  This time it really does have to make the temporary copy, because `00afde4` says *my parent is `badc0de`*, and it needs one that says *my parent is `1111111`*.  Git makes this temporary copy by *comparing* `00afde4` to `badc0de` to see what changed, and making those same changes to `1111111`.  We don't know or care what hash ID this new temporary commit gets, because now it's time to fire up your editor again and *restore* the missing lines that you took out last time.

If you've forgotten what the missing lines are, you can find them easily: compare commit `badc0de`—which is still in your repository—to its parent, using `git show badc0de` for instance.  Get those lines into your work-tree files, using your editor.  Write out the files, exiting the editor.  Run `git add` on those files, and then, again, run `git commit --amend`.

Git now shoves the temporary commit out of the way, making a new commit that's like `00afde4` except that:

- it lists `1111111` as its parent, and
- it has the lines restored from `badc0de`.

Again, we have no idea what hash this *will* have, but let's just call it `2222222` here so that we can talk about it.

Now you can run `git rebase --continue` again.  At this point the only remaining instruction is `pick 9abcdef`.  So Git compares `9abcdef` against its parent `00afde4` to see what changed, makes those same changes to the snapshot in `2222222`, and makes a new commit out of that.  Let's call the new copy `3333333`.

Git now has:

```
3333333  (copy of) Subject of last commit
2222222  (copy of) Second to last commit (now with more stuff)
1111111  (copy of) The commit that you disliked (but now improved)
ba5eba5  A commit you're OK with
```

Commit `3333333` really *is* identical to `9abcdef`, *except* that `3333333` says *my parent is `2222222`*.

Since the copying is now complete, `git rebase` does its last trick: it makes your branch name, whatever name that is, identify copy `3333333` instead of original `9abcdef`, and exits the detached HEAD mode by checking out the re-adjusted branch.  So now if you have Git look at commits starting at the current one and working backwards, you see `3333333`, then `2222222`, then `1111111`, then `ba5eba5`, and so on.  The original commits—the ones you've replaced with the new and improved copies—are invisible.  They're still *in* your repository (for about a month), but they are now hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

@karlosss  `git rebase -i commit-id-test` ，  will show the all the commit-id and commit-msg after commit-id-test, then you can edit the commit-msg avoid ctrl-c/v.

e.g.

```
pick 90b83db Replace QtMultimedia usage with 4A + gstreamer
pick f55e504 autobuild: introduce autobuild scripts
```